# Event dispatching thread remove from List exception SWING

Tags: java, collections

Hi I have this strange exception when trying to remove a element from list in JPanel which implements the State interface. Here is the code:

```
public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private State state;

    public ButtonListener(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        state.applyMove(state.getMoves().get(0));
    }
}
```

And the JPanel where is the implementation of "applyMove" method:

```
public class RushHourBoard extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, State {
...
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
...

@Override
public State applyMove(Move vehicleMove) {
    VehicleMove move = (VehicleMove) vehicleMove;
    Vehicle moved = move.getVehicle();
    vehicles.remove(moved);
    ...
```

And the trace of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at entrery.rushhour.RushHourBoard.applyMove(RushHourBoard.java:174)
at entrery.rushhour.MyDragDemo$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(MyDragDemo.java:59)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Is this something with UI thread security policy ? Thanks in advances for your help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with exactly what type of concrete List your vehicles variable in fact is, something you've not shown us. It does not support remove.

Comment: How do you create the `vehicles` variable?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels LOL you are so right I was using Arrays.asList()... for testing and that was the problem! Could you please explain what is the difference with the normal List implementations and this ?

Comment: Entrery, all I know is that not all List implementations support the `remove()` method as per the [AbstractList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance assigned to `RushHourBoard.vehicles` does not support removal. Perhaps it is from `Arrays.asList` or `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

`List`, like many in Java collections, is a poor interface. It's so unspecific many of the methods may not be implemented (usefully). Even with a loose contract, many of the collection implementations don't even conform to the minimal terms of the interfaces they implement.

Comment: You are right as the other guys in the comments... Thank you. It was my silly misunderstanding...

Comment: @EnTrERy It's a fair enough question, though surrounded with irrelevant details. I guess the real skill is to isolate the problem.